# ¿Como puedo saber si un dato es una fecha? (VB.NET)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel

Mi intención es conocer si el dato que el usuario ha ingresado, es fecha y que esté en el formato **MySQL** (`YYYY-MM-DD`). Primero hice una consulta con datos tipo fecha a una tabla de **Excel**, pero resulta ser que al hacer una prueba para ver que apañaba la consulta, pude notar que la fecha lo captaba con valores numéricos...

Ejemplo: Una fecha de mi tabla es **"08/16/2005"**, pero al hacer la consulta, me devuelve un número (**38580** en este caso).

No comprendo, ya que es claro que se trata de una fecha, y no un número. Sé que en **VB.NET** tenemos la función `IsDate`, o el `Date.TryParse`... ya he intentado identificarlos haciendo una condición, pero al parecer no funciona. ¿Cómo entonces podria yo hacer para identificar si un valor es de tipo fecha?

```
         If (Not Date.TryParse(valor(0), fecha)) Then
             MsgBox(valor(0))
             errores += 1
          End If
```

Comment: Si conoce las fechas estarán dentro de un cierto rango, se podría probar que sus valores son números enteros y están en ese rango (por ejemplo 36526 - 47483 = 01/01/2000 hasta 12/31/2029). En Excel, las fechas son sólo números enteros y no tienen ningún características distintivas especiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Excel** muestra las fechas con el formato elegido por el usuario, pero internamente las almacena como si fueran [valores numéricos](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Cambiar-el-sistema-de-fecha-el-formato-o-la-interpretaci%C3%B3n-de-un-a%C3%B1o-expresado-con-dos-d%C3%ADgitos-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f#bmlearn_about_date_calculations_and_for).

Desde **VB.NET** se puede usar la función `Date.FromOADate()` para obtener la fecha correspondiente al valor entregado por **Excel**. (*OA = OLE Automation*)

```
    Date.FromOADate(38580)
    ' Resultado: #8/16/2005# '

    ' Para pasar al formato YYYY-MM-DD '
    Date.FromOADate(38580).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    ' Resultado: "2005-08-16" '
```

Para consultar los formatos personalizados para fecha, se puede ir a [este enlace de msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).